# HMM prior on stationary probability

Tags: probability, bayesian, hidden-markov-model, stan

I am trying to model a sensor that when mis-calibrated tends to vibrate alot (or atleast high varying readings). I used a HMM to model these vibrations. [image]

It is known that the sensor was calibrated atleast 50% of the time. The way that I interpret this is that the long term probability (stationary probability) of the HMM chain had the most prominent element >0.5.

**The question** is how do I put this as a prior on my model. If $T$ is my transition matrix I know that I can put a Dirchlet prior on each row, but this isn't reallt going to affect the long term probabilty.

Any ideas on such a prior would be appreciated.

**Side question:** Is there a way to do this on stan? It seems easier to put restrictions on stan since you dont need to worry about normalising constants in stan.

```
data {
int<lower=0> N; //Number of observations
int<lower=0> K; // number of categories
real y[N]; // estimated treatment effects
}
parameters {
simplex[K] theta[K];  // transit probs <-NEED TO PUT PRIOR ON THIS
real mu[K];
real<lower=0> sigma[K];
}
model {
real acc[K];
real lg_alpha[N,K];

// Forward step
for (k in 1:K){
    mu[k] ~ normal(0.0,10.0);
    lg_alpha[1,k] <- normal_log(y[1],mu[k], sigma[k]);
}
for (t in 2:N) {
    for (k in 1:K) {
        for (j in 1:K)
            acc[j] <- lg_alpha[t-1,j] + log(theta[j,k]) + normal_log(y[t],mu[k],sigma[k]);
        lg_alpha[t,k] <- log_sum_exp(acc);
    }
}
increment_log_prob(log_sum_exp(lg_alpha[N]));
}
```

Comment: It may help if you actually provide your model.

Comment: @jaradniemi done